# Confused about 'with' and 'without' method name modification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm not sure how to phrase this question because i don't quite understand what's happening here.

Looking at this old gem for Rails 2.x (Rails version not significant) https://github.com/goncalossilva/subdomain_routes/blob/master/lib/subdomain_routes/routes.rb. The plugin extends Rails routing and does a lot of code like this

```
module Route
def self.included(base)
    [ :add_route, :significant_keys].each { |method| base.alias_method_chain method, :subdomains }
end

def significant_keys_with_subdomains
    significant_keys_without_subdomains.tap do |result|
      if conditions[:subdomains].is_a? Symbol
        result << conditions[:subdomains]
        result.uniq!
      end
    end
  end

 ...
ActionController::Routing::Route.send :include, SubdomainRoutes::Routing::Route
```

The plugin takes the standard Route module  method `significant_keys` and then chains that with its own `:subdomains` method. However in this operation it somehow also builds two methods `significant_keys_with_subdomains` and `significant_keys_without_subdomains`. I don't understand how these methods are invoked or in the case of `significant_keys_without_subdomains`, created. I can't find them in the plugin code, so I'm thinking some kind of metaprogramming magic is happening in rails.

I am not very familiar with the intricacies of alias_method_chain, but can someone who has seen these patterns before help me understand what's happening? The plugin itself is not important, I want to know how the ***with*** and ***without*** methods come about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably seeing the result of a call to `alias_method_chain`. Here's how this works:

```
alias_method_chain :some_awesome_method, :super_powers
```

Essentially creates a new definition for the method `some_awesome_method` and aliases your old method to `some_awesome_method_without_super_powers`. The new method `some_awesome_method` just calls `some_awesome_method_with_super_powers` (so you need to define it). But you always have `some_awesome_method_without_super_powers` which points to your original `some_awesome_method` before `alias_method_chain`.

Here's a link to more info: http://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_method_chain

Comment: Clearly I did not ready the documentation for alias_method_chain closely enough. Thanks for quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

In included hook, [alias_method_chain](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Module/alias_method_chain) create aliases.

FYI: https://github.com/goncalossilva/subdomain_routes/blob/master/lib/subdomain_routes/routes.rb#L46